# How can one layer two aligned images in a scrolling <div> using CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, vertical-alignment

I would like to layer **two aligned images in a scrolling <div>**.

At first I tried:

```
<div style="width:300; height:300; overflow:scroll;">
    <img src="bottom.jpg"
         style="width:400; height:800">                                                                                                                                               
    <img src="top.png"
         style="width:400; height:800; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">                                                                                                                                              
</div>
```

(this is a simplified example -- the actual site has a separate CSS sheet etc.)

I would like the two images to behave as one when the <div> is scrolled, but **the "absolute" positioning of the second image causes it not to scroll at all** and to **go outside the borders** of the <div>.

I have also tried changing the style of the second image to:

```
    <img src="top.png"
         style="width:400; height:800; position:relative; top:-800; left:0;">
```

but then there are **800px of extra white space** in the bottom of my <div>.

Is there any CSS I can use on the second image that will **align it on top of the first image and still allow both of them to be scrolled together**?

**[update]** The working solution is at [ozake.com](http://ozake.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add `position: relative` to the parent (`div`). When you use `position:absolute` if you do not contain that element in a parent set to `relative` it will contain itself within the `body`. SO what's happening is `top.jpg` is scolling with it's parent `div` but `bottom.jpg` is staying with the `body`. Once you contain them both inside the parent, then you can set the 2nd image to `top: 800px` to align it just below the other image

```
<div style="width:300; height:300; overflow:scroll; position: relative;">
   <img src="top.jpg" style="width:400; height:800"/>                                                                                                                                               
   <img src="bottom.jpg" style="width:400; height:800;position:absolute; top:800px; left:0;"/>                                                                                                                                              
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jau4vsy0/2/)

Comment: It works on Safari/Mac, but on the iPad it doesn't work -- I still can't scroll. I think your answer is basically correct and it's just that the iPad is buggy.

Comment: hmm interesting, I just tried it on xcode's ipad simulator and it worked. It's just standard CSS so there isn't any reason it shouldnt work. But I agree that if there is an issue, its with the ipad

Comment: Well, it seems to be working now. I'm actually doing something much more complicated -- a website based on pages that are single large SVG's with a fixed menu floating above. If you go in the next five minutes you can see a sample page at noshock.ozake.com. The point is to make everything zoomable & scrollable except the little floating menu.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/m4ze8t1h/)

If so, here you go:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll;">
    <div id="container" style="position: relative">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/Petrus_Christus_-_Portrait_of_a_Young_Woman_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/785px-Petrus_Christus_-_Portrait_of_a_Young_Woman_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg" style="width:400px;">
        <img src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/04/02/17/07/hat-308003_640.png" style="width:250px; position:absolute; top:75px; left: 125px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Use some units in your style, for example pixels.
If you are styling element with `position absolute` it will be positioned relatively to the document itself, so you should set `position: relative` to a parent element to bind absolutely positioned element to this parent element and not to the whole document. In our case we made a container for our images with `position: relative`.
So we have the `#container` which is scrolling inside our `overflow:scroll` div, and our image aligned relative to this container.